# Optimising HTML tag removal in C#

Tags: c#, optimization

I have some code that removes HTML tags from text. I don't care about the content (script, css, text etc), the important thing, at least for now, is that the tags themselves are stripped out.

This may be entering the theatre of micro-optimisation, however this code is among a small number of functions that will be running very often against large amounts of data, so any percentage saving may carry through to a useful saving from the overall application's perspective.

The code at present looks like this:

```
public static string StripTags(string html)
{
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var insideTag = false;
    var output = new char[html.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < html.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = html[i];
        if (c == '>')
        {
            insideTag = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (!insideTag)
        {
            if (c == '<')
            {
                insideTag = true;
                continue;
            }
            output[currentIndex] = c;
            currentIndex++;
        }
    }
    return new string(output, 0, currentIndex);
}
```

Are there any obvious .net tricks I'm missing out on here? For info this is using .net 4.

Many thanks.

Comment: @Dour High Arch - good question - at present I am letting these perish as this fits with the data I'm parsing.

Comment: If the code is run very often, you probably could get a large speedup by only allocating your output array once (with some sensible size obviously; you could use weak refs if memory would be a problem) and using that when possible. An really similar problem in java got about a 15% speedup by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you copy chars one by one. You might be able to speed it up considerably by only checking where the current section (inside or outside html) ends and then use [Array.copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) to move that whole chunk in one go, this would enable lower level optimizations. (for instance on 64 bit it could copy 4 unicode chars (4 * 2* 8 bit) in one processor cycle). The bits of text in between the tags are probably quite large so this could add up.

Also the stringbuilder documentation mentioned somewhere that becuase it's implemented in the framework and not in C# it has perfomance that you can't replicate in managed C#. Not sure how you could append a chunk you might look into that.

Regards Gert-Jan

Comment: Thank you that's a very smart suggestion, I'm going to have a play and will update!

Comment: You were quite right! An altered algorithm that does a CopyTo on each "chunk" was about 15% faster, which in the context of the times required for each element of the function is very impressive, and enough to make a difference. Thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome, I like micro-optimizing this kind of stuff 8-). Another relatively simple optimization would be to do the searching on one Task (thread) and the copying on a second. Since you're not altering the reading array. The strings should be big enough to keep them apart (so no false sharing).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the following library as it seems to be the best way to interact with html files in .NET: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: The original poster just wants to strip the HTML tags. He doesn't need to manipulate the HTML in any complicated way. The HTML agility pack will add a whole lot of overhead for things that he doesn't need to do.

Comment: What about the HtmlToText class in the AgilityPack ? I think it is made to remove tags.

Comment: @Martin - thanks, if I were looking at more "clever" tag manipulation I would definitely consider the AgilityPack. In this case, though, I'm looking purely for speed optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not solve a non existing problem.

How many times will this method be called? Many! How many? Several thousands? Not enough to warrant optimization.

Can you just do a Parallel.For and speed it up 3-5 times depending on machine? Possibly.

Is your code dependent on lots of other code? Certainly.

Is it possible that you have this:

```
// Some slow code
StripTags(s); // Super fast version
// Some more slow code here
```

Will it matter then how fast is your StripTags?

Are you getting them from a file? Are you getting them from a network? Very rarely the bottleneck is your raw CPU power.

Let me repeat myself:

Do not solve a non existing problem!

Comment: I appreciate your concern - hence my own comment about micro-optimisation. In answer - it will run hundreds of millions of times per day over some HTML which may stretch into 100s of Kb. TBH I can live with the performance of the above function, but it's interesting to explore alternatives with the community. For instance @gjvdkamp provided an answer I wouldn't have considered...

Comment: @Boris very true, most optimization is a complete waste of effort by people optmizing something that is executed very few times. But when you're waiting for hours for an 8-way box to complete some computation, believe me these kind of hacks make all the difference!

Answer (score -1):

You can also encode it:

```
string encodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(stringToEncode);
```

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Googling for [remove html from string](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=16&gs_id=24&xhr=t&q=remove+html+from+string&qe=cmVtb3ZlIGh0bWwgZnJvbQ&qesig=9HbVw2lX7D8SQonZJinSVw&pkc=AFgZ2tmW4MSqtwGPmYGNo4k3j6SGp7WsCCPikQqOm4Jwmf_Ss_Oypu-mL4FHN2nFyjmsDh3vNMXuPVuwgqGN-8sEY-_YsITTfw&pq=remove+html+jquery&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=remove+html+from&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=7f38cb74ed69968b&biw=1429&bih=724) yields many links that talk about using Regular Expressions all similar to the following:

```
public string Strip(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: However, Regex are not made to parse html.

Comment: The regex will be hugely slower. Benchmark it and you'll see it quite clearly that the original solution will be MUCH faster.